# ASP.NET MVC Mismatch error on a google chart

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I'm running into an javascript error with google charts. I've got this to work with a different query but I need the result of the query below to be displayed. The problem as of now is that the chart is not appearing. Any thoughts on debugging this?

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type mismatch. Value 1 does not match type string in column index 0
```

Here's my Controller:

```
  #region Total Hours Per Month
        var querythpmpro = (from r in db.HolidayRequestForms
                            where r.EmployeeID == id
                            group r by r.MonthOfHoliday into g
                            select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(h => h.HoursTaken) }
                           ).OrderBy(e => e.Value);


        var resultthpmpro = querythpmpro.ToList();

        var datachartthpmpro = new object[resultthpmpro.Count];
        int Q = 0;
        foreach (var i in resultthpmpro)
        {
            datachartthpmpro[Q] = new object[] { i.Value, i.Count};
            Q++;
        }
        string datathpmpro = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datachartthpmpro, Formatting.None);
        ViewBag.datajthpmpro = new HtmlString(datathpmpro);

        #endregion
```

And my script:

```
 <script>
var datathpmpro = '@ViewBag.datajthpmpro';
var datassthpmpro = JSON.parse(datathpmpro);
 </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartA);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawChartA() {

    // Create the data table.

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Value');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
    data.addRows(datassthpmpro);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        'title': 'Holiday Hours Taken Per Month',
        'width': 600,
        'height': 350,
        'hAxis': {title: 'Month Number'},
        'vAxis': {title: 'Holiday Hours Taken'},
        'is3D': true,
        'legend': 'none'
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartTHPMpro_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I'd like the result to have a google chart appear that uses the query above.

Comment: It looks like in the script column zero is Value and column 1 is Count.  The error message indicates that in c# you are getting an integer and then try to convert to a string.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure where in c# am I converting it to a string though

Comment: @jdweng I converted Value to a string, and it worked!! Thanks! If you answer I'll mark as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seem coming from these lines, which mismatched between data types of `i.Value` and defined column data type in `google.visualization.DataTable` instance:

```
// Controller - returns i.Value as int
datachartthpmpro[Q] = new object[] { i.Value, i.Count };

// JS - defined as string column
data.addColumn('string', 'Value');
```

Assumed that `i.Value` contains integer value, if you want to keep `addColumn` as is then you should pass it as string with `ToString()`:

```
datachartthpmpro[Q] = new object[] { i.Value.ToString(), i.Count };
```

Or if you want to use integer instead without changing controller action code, you may try `number`:

```
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
```

However if you want to pass `Value` column as integer with `addRow()` while keeping `data.addColumn('string', 'Value')` setting, you could try `parseInt()` when iterating array:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Value');

for (var i = 0; i < datassthpmpro.length; i++) {
    intVal = parseInt($.trim(datassthpmpro[i][0]));
    data.addRow([intVal, datassthpmpro[i][1]]);
}
```

References:

[Google Charts - DataTables and DataViews](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews)

[addRow() Function Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#addrow)